# Replace Javascript on-the-fly

Tags: javascript, web, intellij-idea

this questions pops up again and again across the internet (even on SO), but I haven't found a satisfying solution to this problem:

**How can we change/replace Javascript code in a running web application, without reloading the page?**

Many people answer this with "you cannot, because it is impossible". Some experiments with IntelliJ IDEAs live edit plugin proves me that it is possible. But I don't want to be bound to an IDE for this feature. (Bonus: browser independent)

[Here is what I tried:](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?utm_source=dcc)

1. add //# sourceURL=whatever.js to my dynamically loaded script
2. add folder to Chrome containing whatever.js
3. mapping the local whatever.js to the network whatever.js
4. changing code in either does not affect the web-page at all. In fact editing the network-side file results in a oddish "flashing" of the dev tools.

Please understand that I do not expect the changed JS to magically apply to the webpage once I change it, but I expect it to use the new code when the execution point is passed again.

Example:

1. Given a button that triggers 'alert(1);'
2. Change to 'alert(2);'
3. I expect the button to trigger 'alert(2);'

Having many dependencies and a huge script that is triggered pretty late in a workflow it is really a big problem for me to refresh the page, so I need to find a solution that works on-the-fly.

Comment: please add the relevant code to the question, please have a look here: [mcve]

Comment: intellij might be running a user-script  from a plugin to the browser not just client-side javascript.

Comment: @NinaScholz I'd like to but I really can't. It's a big grails web-application with many dependencies. The goal of my question was to start initiate a discussion around this topic, as it is obviously possible to replace JS in 2016. It would be awesome to have such a feature in all browsers or via an external tool.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: What you ask for is really tricky and you can find security problems if you allow this in your applications, anyway it is not impossible.

---

**BUT** if you want to achieve your example follow this steps:

Make a code snippet like this:

```
var message = "1";   // this must be a global variable!!!!

function showMessage() {
    alert(message);
}
```

> Given a button that triggers 'alert(1);'

Make button call a function ie: `onclick='showMessage()'`

> Change to 'alert(2);'
>   I expect the button to trigger 'alert(2);'

Now it's easy, When you detect the event that implies to change the alert message to `2` you just need to change `message` value:

```
message = "2";
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: Livereload**

I would say as long it's for develop reasons you can use livereload on your server.

Depends of your server type. I'm note big expert in apach, glassfish and other java's world stuff, but in world of `JS` (nodejs) this is a shorter way.

(link for [npm-livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload))

Hack: You can handle static-files such as js, css with simple node.js server with built-in livereload.

**Option 2: jRebel**

I'm not sure about `js` but perhaps [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) can handle this issue. Anyway it's a good addition to the develop process - at least it would make a java's "hot reload: for you.

**Option 3: Monkey-patching**

You can use [monkey-patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) techniques: Each function in js it's just a string, you can turn `string` -> `function` with `new Function()`.

just like:

```
var foo = {
  sum: function (a, b) {return a+b;}
}

//...

obj.sum = new Function(....) //Now you're replaced the original code
```

check [this article](http://me.dt.in.th/page/JavaScript-override/) about graceful way to do monkey-patching.

*And small advertising of my lib for monkey-patching: [monkey-punch](https://github.com/se-panfilov/monkey-punch)*

**Option 4: Attach new  tag**

You can attach js files with:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://somedomain.com/somescript";
$("head").append(s);
```

You're also able to remove dom elements (scripts, styles) and attach new at anytime.

Comment: Are you talking about http://livereload.com/ ? I found this during my research but there is no word about javascript. We are using grails here, btw.

Comment: Actually I'm worked only with gulp and grunt plugins (similar to ant) based on livereload. Usually livereload should reload all the stuff, like js, css and etc. In JS word we use bundler (like webpack), something like browsersync (check it, btw) and simple server with livereload.

Comment: @bytespirit are you try Jrebel?

Comment: From the livereload web page: "Would love, but doesn't seem possible: live JS reloading"